# Segfault when returning a value from C to R using .Call (incompatible pointer types returning)

Tags: c, r, segmentation-fault

I am learning to use the C programming language and am having a problem probably of incompatible pointer types returning.

I have a text file with two columns that is read by R as a data.frame. After reading this i want to perform a .Call for a function in C that will read that date.frame and will return the value for a variable in R, however a segfault error occurs when trying to return the value. I can not find the solution to this problem, can anyone help me?

The text file is structured in two columns as in the example below.

```
Q0045   YJL166W
Q0045   YDL085W
Q0045   YDR119W-A
```

Here is the C code for reading the data.frame.

```
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>
#include <R.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char **test(SEXP lst){
  int i,elLength;
  int len = length(lst);
  SEXP col1, col2;
  char ***target = malloc(sizeof(char **) *len);
  col1 = VECTOR_ELT(lst, 0);
  col2 = VECTOR_ELT(lst, 1);
  elLength = length(col1);
  target[0] = malloc(sizeof(char *) * elLength);
  target[1] = malloc(sizeof(char *) * elLength);
  for (i=0; i<elLength; i++) {
    target[0][i] = CHAR(STRING_ELT(col1, i));
    target[1][i] = CHAR(STRING_ELT(col2, i));

  }

  return target;
}
```

After this i create the .so file with the command line in terminal:

```
R CMD SHLIB test.c
```

And finally the code in R that read the file and execute the .Call.

```
dyn.load("/home/lab/test.so")
fileR = data.frame(read.table("file.txt", sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
fileFromC = .Call("test", fileR)
```

After that i got the error running in R from terminal:

```
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x310000c0, cause 'memory not mapped'
```

If i only print and return R_NilValue the error don't show. But i need the return of C process to a new variable.

Comment: You can not use the memory after it was `free`d, so why return it?

Comment: Also `target` is of type `char ***` but the return type of the function is `char **`.

Comment: Why is `target` a `char ***`? As far as I understand your code your loop copies characters, not strings. And why is your format `%s %s\n` if you want to print out characters? You use the string length from column 1 for your string allocation and loop. What is supposed to happen when the string in col2 is shorter than the one in col1?

Answer (score 0):

`malloc()` is not the correct way for handling memory allocation in R extensions.

Please have a look at the R documentation, section [6.1 Memory allocation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Memory-allocation)

> 6.1.1 Transient storage allocation
>
> Here R will reclaim the memory at the end of the call to .C, .Call or .External. Use
>
> ```
> char *R_alloc(size_t n, int size)
> ```
>
> which allocates n units of size bytes each.

i.e. you use this allocator for the memory you want to `return` from your C API.

Comment: also, the `free` instructions should be removed.

Comment: I changed the line of code that does the memory allocation and also removed the free instructions as the example but the error persists.

    char ***target = (char *) R_alloc(len, sizeof(char **));

Comment: Are you sure R can handle raw, unstructured C data as return value? Shouldn't you construct a R data structure, e.g. something like `VECTOR` or `MATRIX`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Stefan. I will try.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do what I needed with the code below. Thanks to everyone who cooperated.

```
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>
#include <R.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char **stripList(SEXP lst){
  int i, j, elLength;
  int len = length(lst);
  char *rans;
  SEXP col1, col2;
  char ***target = (char *) R_alloc(len, sizeof(char **));

  col1 = VECTOR_ELT(lst, 0);
  col2 = VECTOR_ELT(lst, 1);

  elLength = length(col1);

  SEXP ans = PROTECT(Rf_allocMatrix(STRSXP,elLength, len));

  target[0] = malloc(sizeof(char *) * elLength);
  target[1] = malloc(sizeof(char *) * elLength);
  for (i=0; i<elLength; i++) {
    target[0][i] = CHAR(STRING_ELT(col1, i));
    target[1][i] = CHAR(STRING_ELT(col2, i));
  }

for (int i = 0; i < elLength; i++) for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) 
  SET_STRING_ELT(ans, i + j * elLength, Rf_mkChar(target[j][i]));

  UNPROTECT(1);

  return ans;
}
```